# Save Draft Message Using Java Mail API?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Currently im doing as following,

```
@Override
public void saveDraftMessage(MimeMessage draftMessage) throws MessagingException 
{
    Folder draftsMailBoxFolder = imapsStore.getFolder("inbox");//[Gmail]/Drafts
    draftsMailBoxFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);    
    draftMessage.setFlag(Flag.DRAFT, true);
    MimeMessage draftMessages[] = {draftMessage};
    draftsMailBoxFolder.appendMessages(draftMessages);
}
```

It works but , as you could see message is being appended to "inbox" folder without complain from server end !

Is there any kind of validation or an alternative method to ensure that message is saved as Draft only at appropriate place.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.  You are asking it to write to the inbox.. why would it not write to the inbox?

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit confused as well. You can't change how the server validates things using the Java Mail API, it's just a client. If the server allows you to store a message in your inbox, the only thing you can really do is not store it there. I'm not sure why that's a problem.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/
Take a look at the javax.mail documentation. If you're talking about gmail specificically:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/
I have zero experience with gmail API's but Google's documentation is good. Labels appear to basically be a folder and a fair amount of IMAP clients simply mark drafts as a separate folder. I would say that "imapsStore" in your variable name is a red flag if there ever was one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested above, you need to store your draft messages in a different folder.  You can choose the name of that folder.  If you're only using Gmail and you want to be consistent with what Gmail is doing, saving it in the folder Gmail uses ("[Gmail]/Drafts"?) would make sense.  Remember to delete the message from the folder when you send it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip..
"Remember to delete the message from the folder when you send it....."