# javamail: why IMAPStore.connect switch to port 993 even if mail.imap.ssl.enable=false and port=143?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

In the following code (an IBM Domino 9.0.1 java agent) i am trying to connect via port 143 no SSL to IMAP store.

```
package com.fm;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.util.*;
public class JSaveImap {
    private Store store=null;
    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private javax.mail.Session mailSession=null;
    private boolean doDebug; 

    public JSaveImap() {
        System.out.println("Creato oggetto");
    }

    public void saveMessage(MimeMessage message, String folderName) throws MessagingException 
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524716/save-draft-message-using-java-mail-api

        Folder folder=null;
        if (folderName.length()>0) {
            folder= store.getFolder(folderName);
        } else {
            folder= store.getFolder("inbox");
        }       
        if (doDebug) {System.out.println("Folder aperto:" + folder.getFullName());}
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        //draftMessage.setFlag(Flag.DRAFT, true);
        MimeMessage arrMessage[] = {message};
        folder.appendMessages(arrMessage);
        folder.close(false);
        folder=null;
    }

    public boolean connect(String pHost, String pPort, String pUser, String pPassword,boolean doDebug) {
        boolean retVal=false;
        this.doDebug=doDebug;
        if (doDebug) {System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+ ".connect");}
        if (!(pHost.equalsIgnoreCase(host) && pPort.equalsIgnoreCase(port) && pUser.equalsIgnoreCase(user) && pPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password))) {
            // parametri differenti, resetta connessione precedente
            recycle();
            host=pHost;
            port=pPort;
            user=pUser;
            password=pPassword;
        }
        System.out.println("Host: " + host + ", port: " + port + ", user: " + user + ", password: " + password);
        try {
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " connettiamo?");
            //Properties props = System.getProperties();        
            Properties props =new Properties();         //Nuove proprietà per non avere conflitti con quelle gia in uso ad altri account IMAP
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
            if (port.length()>0) {
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", port);
            }
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "false");         //credo che non serva, oltretutto default =false, poi dovrebbe venire parametrico dall'account
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");
            mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            if (doDebug) {
                System.out.println("Proprietà correnti ************************************************************");
                Enumeration keys = props.keys();
                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
                    String value = (String)props.get(key);
                    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
                }
            }

            if ( doDebug) { mailSession.setDebug(true); }
            store = mailSession.getStore("imap");
            //store=mailSession.getStore(new URLName("imap",host,Integer.parseInt(port),null,user,password));
            //store.connect(host, user, password);
            store.connect(host, Integer.parseInt(port), user, password);
            System.out.println("connesso allo store "+ host + " for " +user);
            retVal=true;
        } catch(NoSuchProviderException ne) {
            System.out.println("Exception in class " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName() + 
                    " method: "+ ne.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()+ 
                    ", row: " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber() + ": " + ne.toString());

            //Questa eccezione non la gestisco perchè è nel caso in cui il provider non supporti
            // il protocollo. Lo escludo per ora             
            ne.printStackTrace();
            //throw new MessagingException("Errore nella connessione al provider");
        } catch (MessagingException ne) {
            //throw new MessagingException ("MessagingException durante connessione:"+e.getMessage(),e);
            System.out.println("Exception in class " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName() + 
                    " method: "+ ne.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()+ 
                    ", row: " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber() + ": " + ne.toString());
            ne.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception ne) {
            System.out.println("Exception in class " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName() + 
                    " method: "+ ne.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()+ 
                    ", row: " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber() + ": " + ne.toString());
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (doDebug) System.out.println("Connect terminata");

        return retVal;
    }

    public void recycle() {
        try {
            host="";
            port="";
            user="";
            password="";
            //if (folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true);}
            if (store!=null) {
                if (store.isConnected()) {store.close();}
            }

        } catch (Exception ne) {
            System.out.println("Exception in class " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName() + 
                    " method: "+ ne.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()+ 
                    ", row: " + ne.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber() + ": " + ne.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Why I am getting Exception for port 993 as in message

**Couldn't connect to host, port: 172.17.0.247, 993;**

**Output:**

```
Proprietà correnti ************************************************************
mail.imap.port: 143
mail.imap.ssl.enable: false
mail.imap.timeout: 5000
mail.imap.connectiontimeout: 5000
mail.store.protocol: imap
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
**DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "172.17.0.247", port 143, **
isSSL false
Exception in class com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore method: protocolConnect, row: 731: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, 
**port: 172.17.0.247, 993; timeout 5000;**
nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Agent Manager: Agent  error: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 172.17.0.247, 993; timeout 5000;   nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:731)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at com.fm.JSaveImap.connect(JSaveImap.java:86)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a getDefaultInstance behaviour due to previous IMAP connection

[How to change JavaMail port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8771167/5446522)

Comment: Right, it's a [common mistake](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Many thanks Bill, I have seen your name in various Java.net documents. It's a great pleasure get your comment here!!